# Account unlock and/or password reset on Developer Accounts

Tags: marketing-cloud, forgot-your-password

How do we get a Developer Account Unlocked first and then get a Password Reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent an email to help@exacttarget.com and asked them to reset my password supplying my username. My password was reset by the end of the day.

Comment: Is this still valid?

Comment: SFMC sunsetted their Dev Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

That's awful, the easiest way is to click the password reset button if you have access to the email account. If that's not possible then you'll need to contact salesforce support through their success community. You can use this web address https://help.salesforce.com/HTUnauthContactSupport. I believe from my last experience like this they will need to you provide a versification via fax on signed document with your companies letterhead on it.

Comment: And.... if it is a personal dev account.... it's impossible for them to unlock it.

Comment: Doh...using the password reset button says I don't have a security question set-up (again, doh!). It is a Marketing Cloud Developer Edition Account. I can always just spin up a new one, but that seems wasteful. :-)